# R Is there a way to get the wanted rows and its neighbor in a simple way

Tags: r, dataframe

Sometimes we want not only the rows satisfy our condition, but its adjacent rows to do a comparison, I want to get the wanted row, and the n rows above it and/or n rows below it.

To be more specific, suppose the condition give me row 3,6,7

I want row 1,2,3,4,5 to compare 3
need row 4,5,6,7,8 to compare 6
and row 5,6,7,8,9 to compare 7

after eliminate duplication, I get row 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I knew this could be handled by writing a function my self and it is not hard

I just wondering if there is any package focus on the neighbor of the rows, since many estimation need not only the rows but also its neighbor

Comment: Your output is not clear.  If you are comparing a vector with a matrix or data.frame, then `v1 <-  c(3, 6, 7);m1 <- rbind(1:5, 4:8, 5:9);m1 == v1`

Comment: Thanks! I have an answer, that may be give you more clue on what I am thinking

Answer (score 0):

I have find the way(write the function myself), but if anyone know any package aimed for this please tell me

extend the number to a vector centered with this value by 2, consider the boundary case, by default the first row is 1 and we didn't reach the end

```
getAdjacentNum = function(x,lowerbound = 1,upperbound = x+2){
start = x - 2
if (x - lowerbound == 1)
  start = x - 1
if (x == lowerbound)
  start = x
end = x + 2
if (upperbound - x == 1)
end = x + 1
if (upperbound == x)
  end = x
result = seq(from = start,to = end,by = 1)
return(result)
}
```

vectorize this function

```
getAdjacentNumV = Vectorize(getAdjacentNum,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

combine the result and deal with the duplication

```
getAdjacentIndex = function(index){
  unique(unlist(getAdjacentNumV(index)))
}
```

example:

```
getAdjacentIndex(c(1,5,29))
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 27 28 29 30 31
```